# How to fech data through scrapy from search engine

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looking for help as I'm learning python and evolving myself, I came across scrapy where data can be fetched so just curious to know how can this be done from a search engine, for example, https://www.1mg.com/, here how can I pull data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not tried anything but are looking for leads. However, there are plenty of tutorials in internet to start scraping in Python. A good start for Scrapy can be this one:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3

Alternatively, since you are in Python environment, you can check out [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

And since you are a beginner in scraping, please learn about robots.txt file and why it must be respected. A good read would be this one:

https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/how-to-read-and-respect-robots-file

Some other ethics that you need to be aware of while scraping:

https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/